# Is it feasible to use Vary: headers with If-none-match: to improve caching?

Tags: cache, http-headers, proxy

As we all know, sending a response header `Vary: Some-Header` causes (or should cause) caches to store different variants of the response, one for each value of `Some-Header:` it encounters in requests.
However, this method has drawbacks with headers that show enormous variation, such as `User-Agent:` or `Accept-Language:`.

Let's say our server wants to vary based on such a very variable header, but really just serves a handful of variants. I think the followin *almost* works:

- The server uses all request headers to determine which variant to serve; let's assume it decides to send variant #42
- The server sends `Etag: variant42-version1` and `Vary: If-none-match`
- The next time this user wants to access the page, it presumably adds `If-none-match: variant42-version1` and therefore tries to retrieve that from the cache
- However, there is no such entry in the cache. But a fresh query from the server will cause a response with that Etag again, which will be cached for the future
- If the same user wants to access the page a third time, he will again add `If-none-match: variant42-version1` and this time be served the cached content

The problem with this is the initial case of no Etag at all. Those are the first time visitors for which the complicated evaluation which version to serve needs to be performed - but specifically for these we would still need to vary with the original headers instead of If-none-match ... a vicious circle.

Can this be made work? (Or can the desired effect of reducing cachable variants be achieved differently?)

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to achieve something similar to either A/B testing or serving specific versions of a page based on data such as a user-agent string. Can you please advise the reason if possible, why you are trying to achieve variant served pages, that will make answering making it work or achieving the desired effect differently, easier.

Comment: @PlanetScaleNetworks it could be just a dynamic serving of mobile/desktop content, which is truly popular

Comment: @Evgeniy Actually, my original desire was mainly for `Accept-Language:`. If I only have an English and a German version available, and a client says "I'm a natve speaker of French, quite good at Russian, understand quite a bit of German, but no English at all" the server will send the German version; thus I'd rather have this occupy only the same slot as the German version served to a client stating "I understand German and nothing else"

Comment: If you find this answer helpful to you, please [accept this answer as
correct](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question and your clarification comment you would be better served using the URL rather than a header in order to best deal with downstream caching servers. In other words the first time you get the connection check the language header and then redirect them to the appropriate content via URL (something like `www.domain.com/en/` or `www.domain.com/de`). By doing this you will not have to do anything special for caching servers. Additionally some caching servers are not correctly configured to support variants on pages and so can break the header based language changes (the user wants German language but the English version is cached and returned from the caching server).

Even the largest sites on the internet such as Microsoft put the language code into the URL to ensure the best support for downstream caching servers.